# Python requests library takes for ever to make get request

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I want to make a Python get request using the requests library.
My Code looks like this:

```py
import requests
ip = $someIP
headers = {
        'Key': '$APIKEY',
        'Accept': 'application/json',} 
data = {
        'ipAddress': ip
        }  
r = requests.get('https://api.abuseipdb.com/api/v2/check', headers=headers, params=data)
data = r.json()
```

It works as expected but takes nearly 42 seconds to complete. It doesn't seem to be my Internet connection or the server which cause the problem.
I tracked the request with wireshark and for 41 seconds nothing appeared, after that the request was made. It seems like requests waits 41 seconds and then makes the request. Also using cURL it took sub 1 seconds:

```
curl -G https://api.abuseipdb.com/api/v2/check -d "ipAddress=$someIP" -H "Key: $APIKEY"   -H "Accept: application/json"
```

I can't figure out what exactly the problem is. Maybe it has something to do with the headers? Is there another way to make a get request using Python?

Comment: Try and adding the `verify=False` and see if this is taking this much time - if not the problem is not with python `requests`, most likely with the ssh handshake.

Comment: Still takes the same amount of time.

Comment: Also sometimes it doesn't take that long. 1 out of 10 times it makes the request in under 2 seconds.

Comment: mmmm try and use this library instead and see what happen : https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html

Comment: urllib2 doesn't seem to work with a get request and data/header.

Comment: `-d` flag in `curl` != `params=...` in `requests`

Comment: @finefoot Not really, the script i wrote only runs once a week so it doesn’t really matter if it takes 10 mins or more to get through all requests. It isn’t perfect, but doesn’t really bother me either